# Don't insist on an edit summary that will dropped

Tags: bug, tags, suggested-edits, edit-summary

My reputation here on MSO is 1056, so I do not have [the edit privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit). However, I can propose edits, so I see an *edit* button on others' posts. When I try to edit a post, if my edit is only the addition of a tag, it gets approved automatically rather than sent to a queue, and whatever I wrote as the edit summary gets changed to "edited tags".

All right, so the edit summary is going to be changed anyway, I thought, so I might as well leave it blank. No — the software tells me I have to leave an edit summary. It's enforcing the inclusion of an edit summary that it will then ignore! This makes no sense; it should allow no edit summary if the only edit is to the tags.